# Using aer.bst, removing dashed duplicate authors

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using aer.bst for my bibtex bibliography in LyX 2.1 and I am trying to print recurrent author names instead of using a dash. All the previous Tex.stackexchange.com advice on removing the dashing feature does not seem to apply to the aer style which uses a feature called \bysame to to indicate that authors names have been duplicated in separate entries. If it helps, aer.bst uses natbib.

A minimal working example of what this looks like is below:
[image: Bibliography with dashes for duplicate authors]

Comment: Please add the code of your [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a copy of `aer.bst` and modify it to bypass the comparison of author (and editor) names. The following [patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29) should do the trick. In the patch, the modified bibliography style file is named `aer2.bst`. I have edited two lines in the function `make.list.label`.

```
--- aer.bst 2014-01-12 01:23:55.000000000 +0200
+++ aer2.bst    2014-08-20 18:19:51.121860358 +0300
@@ -633,10 +633,10 @@

 FUNCTION {make.list.label}
 {author.field field.used =
-    { prev.author author compare.names format.authors
+    { author format.authors
          author 'prev.author :=}
     { editor.field field.used =
-        { prev.author editor compare.names format.editors
+        { editor format.editors
                 editor 'prev.author := }
         { organization.field field.used =
             { "The " #4 organization chop.word
```

*Example (uses LaTeX, but LyX should be no different)*

[image: Output with the modified bibliography style]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{aer}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{baker2007a,
  title={Investor Sentiment and the Cross-Section of Stock Returns},
  author={Baker, Malcolm and Wurgler, Jeffrey},
  journal={Journal of Finance},
  volume={61},
  number={4},
  pages={1645--1680},
  year={2007},
}
@article{baker2007b,
  title={Investor Sentiment in the Stock Market},
  author={Baker, Malcolm and Wurgler, Jeffrey},
  journal={Journal of Economic Perspectives},
  volume={21},
  number={2},
  pages={129--151},
  year={2007},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{aer2}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```